# Samples Gallery on Eclipse similar to Eclipse marketplace

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, plugins, eclipse-marketplace, customizing

I want to implement a functionality in eclipse similar to eclipse market place. The main aim to show the list of samples/archives which are to be listed in the UI and the same can be imported into the Eclipse workspace.

Can some one guide me on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps for eclipse 3.X :

- Figure a way to place or choose the directory where your updatesite are
- Parse it and display to your user a list of choices (as a combox in coolbar, or a button that display a list ....)
- Create URI pointing to the selection
- initialize a P2Agent
- Load Repository
- Proceed to Install (I assume it's only for installing plugin, not update)
- Retrieve from install a `provisioningJob` and `schedule()` it

Check [vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseP2Update/article.html) but beware that `UpdateOperation()` applies to plugin already in installed in eclipse, and `InstallOperation()` is for new plugin.

[OperationFactory doc](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fequinox%2Fp2%2Foperations%2FOperationFactory.html) from which you get the operation you need.

[Additional source, specially in the end of the link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application)